# How to quickly compare very large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two `tens of millions` of rows of dataframe `df1` and `df2`, `df1` is the main dataframe. Both have two columns: `date` and `code`. After deduplication, there are about `5,000` rows of `date` and `code` each. `Date+code` is not repeated. How to use the fastest method Find out that there is `date+code` in `df1`, but there is no `data+code` in df2?
The method I use now is a for loop date, compared with `np.setdiff1d`, about 3 `date` per second, how can I optimize it?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

......

df1['s'] = df1.date + df1.code
df2['s'] = df2.date + df2.code

df = pd.DataFrame()

dates = df1.date.drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False)

for date in tqdm(dates, total=len(dates)):
    t1 = df1[df1.date == date]
    t2 = df2[df1.date == date]
    s = np.setdiff1d(t1.s, t2.s)
    if len(s) == 0:
        continue
    t = pd.DataFrame(s)
    pd.concat([df, t])
```

It may be faster to use `np.setdiff1d` directly, but it takes too long to estimate the total time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

......

df1['s'] = df1.date + df1.code
df2['s'] = df2.date + df2.code
s=np.setdiff1d(df1.s,df2.s)
```

The sample data is as follows:

```
print(f'len of df1:{len(df1)}')
print(f'len of df2:{len(df2)}')

print(f'columns of df1:{df1.columns}')
print(f'columns of df2:{df2.columns}')

print(f'df1 len of codes drop_duplicates:{len(df1.code.drop_duplicates())}')
print(f'df2 len of codes drop_duplicates:{len(df2.code.drop_duplicates())}')

print(f'df1 len of dates drop_duplicates:{len(df1.date.drop_duplicates())}')
print(f'df2 len of dates drop_duplicates:{len(df2.date.drop_duplicates())}')

print(df1.head(10))
print(df2.head(10))
```

```
len of df1:11389167
len of df2:11356323

columns of df1:Index(['date', 'code'], dtype='object')
columns of df2:Index(['date', 'code'], dtype='object')

df1 len of codes drop_duplicates:4394
df2 len of codes drop_duplicates:4398

df1 len of dates drop_duplicates:7412
df2 len of dates drop_duplicates:7412

       date       code
0  20210416  000001.SZ
1  20210416  000002.SZ
2  20210416  000004.SZ
3  20210416  000005.SZ
4  20210416  000006.SZ
5  20210416  000007.SZ
6  20210416  000008.SZ
7  20210416  000009.SZ
8  20210416  000010.SZ
9  20210416  000011.SZ

       date       code
0  20210416  689009.SH
1  20210416  000001.SZ
2  20210416  000002.SZ
3  20210416  000004.SZ
4  20210416  000005.SZ
5  20210416  000006.SZ
6  20210416  000007.SZ
7  20210416  000008.SZ
8  20210416  000009.SZ
9  20210416  000010.SZ
```

df.merge is very fast ,thanks to @Andrej Kesely

```
df1['a'] = 1
df2['b'] = 1

print('start merge')
start = time()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['date', 'code'])
stop = time()
print(f'merge time:{stop - start} s')

df = df[df.a.isnull() | df.b.isnull()]

print('start saving df')
start = time()
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
stop = time()
print(f'saving time: {stop - start} s')
```

result is:

```
start merge
merge time: 11.73848009109497 s
start saving df
saving time: 0.3139007091522217 s
```

Comment: So `df1` has ~5000 columns and `df2` has ~5000 columns? Have you tried `.merge()`?

Comment: can you add a sample input/output dataframe?